# Pop window is not filling full screen in nexus 7 and samsung galaxy s4???

Tags: android, view

I need to show pop up window below the button(Menu) in actionbar when pressed on it. Everything is working fine on all device except Nexus 7 and Samsung galaxy S4. The amazing problem is Pop window is not filling on whole screen.i found this problem in high resolution device such as i mentioned above. here i have attached screen shot which is clearly showing the problem.[image]

As a result i am facing issue on measuring  position of arrow head from left which i need to calculate to shift  arrow head  dynamically when user press menu. here i am getting trouble in showing arrow head exactly below the clicked menu on action bar.

**PROBLEM**

1)Pop window is not filling on device screen although layout prams is match parent
2) Arrow head has shifted right and shift distance is equal to gap on left most side of screen.

**WHAT I DID**

more is a clicked view (menu) on actionbar

```
    more.getLocationOnScreen(xy);
    int[] parentxy = new int[2];
    ((LinearLayout) aerrowHead.getParent()).getLocationOnScreen(parentxy);
    final Rect rect = new Rect();
    rect.left = xy[0];
    Log.v("More", "Left :" + xy[0] + "bottom" + xy[1]);
    Log.v("arrow head parent", "Left :" + parentxy[0] + "bottom"
            + parentxy[1]);
    rect.top = xy[1] - more.getWidth() / 2;
    rect.right = xy[0] + more.getWidth();
    rect.bottom = xy[1] + more.getHeight() / 2;
    popup.showAsDropDown(more);
    android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int marginLeft = xy[0] - parentxy[0] + more.getWidth() / 2
            - aerrowHead.getWidth() / 2;
    layoutParams.setMargins(marginLeft, 0, 0, 0);

    aerrowHead.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    popup.setFocusable(true);
```

and layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/notification_panel_bgcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNotificationTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Notification"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#4A546C" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@null"
            android:divider="#C7C7C8"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@null"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/errorLoadingLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/errorLoadingImage"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_friendrequest"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/load_more_progressbar"
                style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtErrorLoading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
                android:shadowDy="2"
                android:shadowRadius="0.3"
                android:text="Error In Loading"
                android:textColor="#576586"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aerrowHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_notification_popup_arrowhead" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you figure it out ?